# Basic question about convergence of top and penultimate eigenvalues of a sequence of operators.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators, spectral-radius

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}$ $\newcommand{\ab}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}$ $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbf C}$

## Questions

Let $I$ be the unit interval.
Let $H=L^2(I)$ and $T:H\to H$ be a compact self-adjoint operator.
Let $f_n:I\to I$ be a sequence of function in $L^\infty(I)$ such that $f_n\to \mathbf 1$ in $L^\infty$  where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the function $I\to \C$ which takes the value $1$ everywhere.
Define $T_n=f_n T$, that is $T_n:H\to H$ takes $\xi$ to $(T\xi)f _n$, that is, the pointwise product of $T\xi$ and $f_n$.

> **Question 1.**
> I am trying to see if
> $$
> \lambda_{\text{max}}(T_n) \to \lambda_{\text{max}}(T)
> $$
> where $\lambda_\text{max}(T_n)$ denotes the largest eigenvalue of $T_n$ and similarly for $T$.

(We know that since each $T_n$ is compact and has real spectra as argued in the Appendix).

*Progress on the Question 1.* If $\rho$ denotes the spectral radius, then by the spectral radius formula, we have
$$
\rho(T_n) = \limsup_{k\to \infty} \norm{(T_n)^k}^{1/k} = \limsup_{k\to \infty} \norm{(f_n T)^k}^{1/k}
$$
If $n$ is large enough then we have $\norm{f_n-\mathbf 1}\leq \varepsilon$. Also, $\norm{fT}\leq \norm{f}_\infty\norm{T}$ and similalry $\norm{(fT)^k}\leq \norm{f}_\infty^k\norm{T}^k$, which gives
$$
\rho(T_n) \leq \lim\sup_{k\to \infty} \norm{f_n}_\infty \norm{T}\leq (1+\varepsilon)\limsup_{k\to \infty} \norm{T} = (1+\varepsilon) \rho(T)
$$
Similarly we can show that for large enough $n$ we have
$$
(1-\varepsilon)\rho(T) \leq \rho(T_n)
$$
giving that $\rho(T_n)\to \rho(T)$ as $n\to \infty$.
Since the spectrum may have negative values, this does not necessarily give $\lambda_{\text{max}}(T_n)\to \lambda_{\text{max}}(T)$ but is a step in that direction.

Also, if $\lambda_{\text{penmax}}(T)$ denotes the second to largest eigenvalue of $T$, then,

> **Question 2.**
> Is it also true that
> $$
> \lambda_{\text{penmax}}(T_n) \to \lambda_{\text{penmax}}(T)
> $$
> as $n\to \infty$.

If there is something more general known about convergence of spectra (of compact operators or otherwise) then please feel free to share.

## Appendix

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a small positive number and $f:I\to I$ be such that $\norm{f-\mathbf 1}_\infty<\varepsilon$, where $\mathbf 1$ denotes the constant function $1$.
Let $H=L^2(I)$.
Let $T:H\to H$ be a compact operator and  define $fT: H\to H$ as $(fT)\xi = f\ T\xi$ for all $\xi\in H$.

> We will show that if $T$ is a compact self-adjoint operator then $fT$ is compact with all its eigenvalues real.

If $T$ is compact then there is a sequence $(T_n)$ of bounded linear operators on $H$ such that each $T_n$ has finite rank and $T_n\to T$ in operator norm.
Clearly, $fT_n\to fT$ in operator norm.
Since each $fT_n$ is also of finite rank, we see that $fT$ is indeed compact.

For any $g\in L^\infty(I)$ close to $\mathbf 1$ in the $L^\infty$ norm, define an inner product $\ab{\cdot, \cdot}_g$ on $L^2(I)$ as $\ab{\xi, \zeta}_g = \int_I \xi\bar \zeta g\ d\mu$.
It is easy to check that this is indeed an inner product.
Let us write $H_g$ to denote $L^2(I)$ equipped with the inner product $\ab{\cdot, \cdot}_f$.
Then we have
$$
\ab{(fT)\xi, \zeta}_{1/f} = \ab{f\ T\xi, \zeta}_{1/f} = \ab{T\xi, \zeta} = \ab{\xi, T \zeta} = \ab{\xi, f\ T\zeta}_{1/f} = \ab{\xi, (fT) \zeta}_{1/f}
$$
This shows that $fT$ is self-adjoint with respect to the inner product $\ab{\cdot, \cdot}_{1/f}$.

Cross posted on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372312/basic-question-about-convergence-of-top-and-penultimate-eigenvalues-of-a-sequenc).

Comment: In the definition of $T_n$, what do you mean by $f_n(T\xi)$? Isn't $T\xi$ a function on the interval?

Comment: By $f_n(T\xi)$ I mean the pointwise product of the functions $f_n$ and $T\xi$. Let me try to express it differently.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake in your estimate of $\rho(T_n)$ by assuming that $T$ commutes with $f_n$.   Furthermore, the definition of the new inner product given in the appendix only works if $f$ is positive.

Comment: @Ruy Thanks. The working was a bit erroneous in the estimate of $\rho(T_n)$ but the conclusion does not change. I have edited the post to reflect this. I hope it is correct now. Also, I am only working with $f$ valued in $I=[0, 1]$ so it is already positive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am still a little concerned about your statement that $$ \limsup_{k\to \infty}
\|(T_n)^k\|^{1/k} = \limsup_{k\to \infty} \|(f_n T)^k\|^{1/k}.  $$ How would you go about proving this?  Nevertheless I
think the comments in MO will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Also, I am sorry to have overlooked your hypothesis that $f$ takes values in $I$.  I learned an interesting thing from your post: if $T$ is a self-adjoint operator and $U$ is positive and invertible, then $UT$ is similar to a self-adjoint operator and hence shares the nice spectral properties enjoyed by them!  Your proof involving a new inner product could be replaced by $$ UT\sim U^{-1/2}(UT)U^{1/2} = U^{1/2}TU^{1/2} $$ which is self-adjoint!

Comment: @Ruy Thanks for the responses. For the first one, the equality that $\limsup_{k\to \infty} \|T_n^k\|^{1/k} = \limsup_{k\to \infty} \|(f_nT)^k\|^{1/k}$ follows from the definition of $T_n$, since $T_n$ is defined to be equal to $f_nT$. (As stated in the post, $f_nT$ takes $\xi$ to $(T\xi)f_n$, the pointwise product of $T\xi$ and $f_n$.) Yes, the comments in MO are helpful and I think I should be able to complete a proof of it in sometime. It's just that I am unwell these days and also trying to write my thesis.

Comment: I am sorry I misread your statement!